# DisplayMembers in ListBox - Not displaying anything

Tags: c#

In `Form1`, why isn't `myListBox` displaying my `name` property inside of class `Student`

`Form1`

```
private static List<Student> studentListHome = new List<Student>();

...

public void BindData()
        {
            if (studentListHome != null)
            {
                studentListBox.DataSource = studentListHome;
                studentListBox.DisplayMember = "name";
            }
        }

    private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BindData();
            }
```

`Student`

```
    private string name;

    public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return name;
                }
            }
...

public Student(string _name, int _id, string _bday)
        {
            name = _name;
            id = _id;
            bday = _bday;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";`. The property's name is using Pascal case and your code was not.

Comment: The property on your Student class is *N*ame. *n*ame is a private field.

Comment: I have, I also tried `foreach(Student s in studentListHome){studentListBox.DisplayMember = "s.Name";}`

Comment: Put a debugger  if (studentListHome != null) and whats the value in here?.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'name' is a private string.

Try using 'Name' which is your property.

```
studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

Changing

```
studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

To

```
foreach(Student s in studentListHome){
    studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```